# Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType ... Why?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF 5 wit Pocos and I have the following code line:

```
user.Seals.Add(new Seal("token", "flag"));
```

Both User and Seal are EF entities pocos as follows:

```
user.Seals.Add(new UserUnlockSealModel());
```

Where UserUnlockSealModel is the following:

```
public class UserUnlockSealModel : Seal {

  public UserUnlockSealModel() : base(Cryptographer.Salt(32), "UU") { }

} // UserUnlockSealModel
```

But when I use this I get the following error:

Message = "Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'UserUnlockSealModel'."

What am I missing here? Can't I use an entity as a Base Class?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Recently I have got simillar problem, maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854327/map-derived-type-to-the-same-table-in-ef